# Rounding down to varying decimal place counts in Perl

Tags: perl, floating-point

Taking a floating point number, I would like to round down, depending upon a user defined 'bin' size. The bin size therefore will change depending upon user preference. For example, the bin sizes may be 0.5, 0.1, 1 or even 0.01.

My aim is to determine which bin a floating point number will fall into. As an example:

a 0.1 bin size:

```
2348.285 will fall into a 2348.2 bin

238.592 will fall into a 238.5 bin
```

a 0.5 bin size:

```
2348.285 will fall into a 2348.0 bin

238.592 will fall into a 238.5 bin
```

a 0.01 bin size:

```
2348.285 will fall into a 2348.28 bin

238.592 will fall into a 238.59 bin
```

a 1 bin size:

```
2348.285 will fall into a 2348 bin

238.592 will fall into a 238 bin
```

I have looked into rounding in Perl for example, the floor(), sprintf() and also substr() methods, however, none of them do quite want I want to do, or rather, I can't make them do what I want.
What neat code will dynamically change the floor value that the floating point number will round down to given the user-defined bin size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might try [Math::Round](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Math-Round/Round.pm):

```
use Math::Round 'nlowmult';

print nlowmult( .01, 2348.285 ) . "\n";
print nlowmult( .01, 238.592 ) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Subject to [some quirks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666091/simple-perl-for-loop), the round-down-to-arbitrary-bin-size formula is

```
use POSIX 'floor';

$bin = $bin_size * floor( $value / $bin_size )
```

A workaround to the `24.01 / 0.01 => 2400.99999999999996758 =>` rounds to `2400` (for example) is to perturb your input, like

```
$epsilon = 1.0e-12;

$bin = $bin_size * floor( ($value+$epsilon) / $bin_size)
```

or

```
$bin = $bin_size * floor( $value / $bin_size + $epsilon )
```

Note that you may have better luck multiplying by `1/$bin_size` than by dividing by `$bin_size`. For example, you've seen that floating-point arithmetic with the value `0.1` can be trouble, so computing `$value * 10` might not give unexpected results as often as `$value / 0.1`.

(but what's the workaround to the workaround when your actual input is `24.01 - $epsilon` and you intend for that to be rounded down to 24.00?)

Comment: `int` rounds up for negative inputs.